# How to write generic method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a scenario like multiple sections have similar functionality as defined below

```
<html lang="en"> <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#fav_countries_checkboxAll_option").click(function(){  
                $(".fav-color").prop('checked', 'checked');
            });
                    $("#fav_sports_checkboxAll_option").click(function(){  
                $(".fav-sport").prop('checked', 'checked');
            });

        });
        </script> </head> <body>   <h3>Favorite Countries</h3>   <a id="fav_countries_checkboxAll_option"
    href="javascript:void(0);">Select all</a>   <input type="checkbox"
    class="fav-color" name="country1" value="India">India<br/>   <input
    type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country2"
    value="Singapore">Singapore<br/>   <input type="checkbox"
    class="fav-color" name="country3" value="Australia">Australia<br/>  
    <input type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country4"
    value="Ameria">Ameria<br/>   <br/>
         <h3>Favorite Sports</h3>   <a id="fav_sports_checkboxAll_option" href="javascript:void(0);">Select
    all</a>   <input type="checkbox" class="fav-sport" name="sport1"
    value="Cricket">Cricket<br/>   <input type="checkbox"
    class="fav-sport" name="sport2" value="Tennis">Tennis<br/>   <input
    type="checkbox" class="fav-sport" name="sport3"
    value="VolleyBall">VolleyBall<br/>    </body> </html>
```

I feel like I'm duplicating the code for each section. I want like to have generic method which will handle scenario. 
How to achieve this in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there are many ways to achieve your requirement.

- Please consider naming your checkbox with same `name` when grouping.
  This is not compulsory but when you try get list of all checked boxes
  under certain category this becomes helpful. In your case
  FavoriteCountry and FavoriteSport.
- We use the `class` to identify our action element `a` element and attach `click` function
- we use html5 `data` attribute to store the `name` of the checkbox category
  to perform selectall on. in this scenario `data-toselect='favorite_country'`,`data-toselect='favorite_sport'`
- pass the `name` we get from the data attribute `data-toselect` to the `prop` function and update the value to `checked`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".select-all-link").click(function() {
    var toSet = $(this).data("toselect");
    $("input[name='" + toSet + "']").prop('checked', 'checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3>Favorite Countries</h3>
  <a id="fav_countries_checkboxAll_option" class="select-all-link" data-toselect="favorite_country" href="javascript:;">Select all</a>
  <legend>Favorite Countries?</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_country" value="India">India<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_country" value="Singapore">Singapore<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_country" value="Australia">Australia<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_country" value="Ameria">Ameria<br>


  <a id="fav_sports_checkboxAll_option" class="select-all-link" data-toselect="favorite_sport" href="javascript:;">Select all</a>
  <legend>Favorite Countries?</legend>

  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_sport" value="Cricket">Cricket<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_sport" value="VolleyBall">VolleyBall<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_sport" value="Tennis">Tennis<br>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. Is there any way to fetch checkbox name in onChange event

Comment: @arjunan, onchange event of what ? the checkbox ? I would say that would be different question, but it'll be along the lines oif `$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function(){console.log($(this).attr('name'));})` applied on any and all checkboxes on the page

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to find solution for my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using class selector as below

```
 $(".checkAll").click(function(){  
          var relatedCtrls = $(this).attr('related-ctrls')
          if(relatedCtrls)
            $('.'+relatedCtrls).prop('checked', 'checked');
       });

<a id="fav_countries_checkboxAll_option"
    href="javascript:void(0);" class="checkAll" related-ctrls="fav-color">Select all</a> 


<a id="fav_countries_checkboxAll_option"
        href="javascript:void(0);" class="checkAll" related-ctrls="fav-sport">Select all</a>
```

Group all your check all `<a>` tag under single class. Add custom attribute to maintain class name of related controls which will help you to identify set of related controls of that specific `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even without classes or IDs by using `nextUntil()` and `filter()`:

```js
$(function(){
 $("a[id*=checkboxAll]").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('h3').filter("input:checkbox").prop('checked', 'checked');
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Favorite Countries</h3>
<a id="fav_countries_checkboxAll_option" href="javascript:void(0);">Select all</a> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country1" value="India">India<br/> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country2" value="Singapore">Singapore<br/> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country3" value="Australia">Australia<br/> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-color" name="country4" value="Ameria">Ameria<br/> <br/>
<h3>Favorite Sports</h3> 
<a id="fav_sports_checkboxAll_option" href="javascript:void(0);">Select all</a> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-sport" name="sport1" value="Cricket">Cricket<br/> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-sport" name="sport2" value="Tennis">Tennis<br/> <input type="checkbox" class="fav-sport" name="sport3" value="VolleyBall">VolleyBall
```

Edit: I made the `$("a")` selector a bit more specific now to fit into a real application situation.

I chose `"h3"` to be the limiting element for the `nextUntil()` selector. You should pick a selector that reliably fits the structure of your page. This selector or the end of the page needs to occur after each checkbox each group.